# Is there a reason a call to a simple stored procedure via Tedious is taking so long?

Tags: node.js, performance, tedious

I have noticed that when calling a simple stored procedure `CreateStatusReport` that simply does an INSERT into a table, it often takes an unusually long time to execute which I am (for better or worse) assuming has to do with some TDS overhead or perhaps the way I'm invoking it.

Here's the TDS code that's called within a Node.js REST API:

```
function createReport(req, res) {
    let isReleased = false;

    let connection = new Connection(config);  

    connection.on('connect', function(err) {  
        let sql = "CreateStatusReport";

        if (err) console.log("**CN-ERROR", err);

        let request = new Request(sql, (err)=>{
            if (err) {
                console.log("**RQ-ERROR**", err);
            }
        });

        // Check to see if user clicked the "Release" button...
        if (typeof req.body.release != 'undefined')
            isReleased = true;

        request.addParameter('empid', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.empid);
        request.addParameter('userid', TYPES.NChar, req.body.userid);
        request.addParameter('firstname', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.fname);
        request.addParameter('lastname', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.lname);
        request.addParameter('title', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.title);
        request.addParameter('cabinet', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.cabinet);
        request.addParameter('office', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.office);
        request.addParameter('division', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.division);
        request.addParameter('branch', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.branch);
        request.addParameter('perstart', TYPES.VarChar, req.body.periodStart);
        request.addParameter('perend', TYPES.VarChar, req.body.periodEnd);
        request.addParameter('status', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.status);
        request.addParameter('needs', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.needs);
        request.addParameter('goals', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.goals);
        request.addParameter('concerns', TYPES.NVarChar, req.body.concerns);
        request.addParameter('released', TYPES.Bit, isReleased);

        connection.callProcedure(request);

        request.on("requestCompleted", ()=> {
            res.redirect("/kudos")    
        });
    });  
}
```

The stored procedure is very simple so I'll just put the "guts" here:

```
INSERT INTO [status-report] (empid, [userid], firstname, lastname, title,[cabinet], [office], [division], [branch], [period-start], [period-end], [date-posted], [status], needs, goals, concerns, released) 
VALUES (@empid, @userid, @firstname, @lastname, @title, @cabinet, @office, @division, @branch, @perstart, @perend, GETDATE(), @status, @needs, @goals, @concerns, @released)
```

It can take up to several seconds for the record to actually get created into the system and I've no idea why since the system is on a high-performance production system.

Are there some things here I'm overlooking? Any suggestions as to how I can find the root cause?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

```
USE [kudos]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetList]    Script Date: 5/1/2019 4:39:50 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetList]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT 
        [id],
        [empid],
        [lastname] + ', ' + [firstname] AS [name],
        LTRIM(RTRIM([userid])) AS [userid],
        [title],
        [cabinet],
        [office],
        [division],
        [branch],
        CONVERT(nvarchar(10), [period-start], 110) AS [periodstart],
        CONVERT(nvarchar(10), [period-end], 110) AS [periodend], 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(10), [date-posted], 110) AS [dateposted],
        IIF(released = 1, 'Released', 'In Progress') AS [released]
    FROM 
        [status-report] 
    WHERE 
        [date-posted] BETWEEN GETDATE() - 21 AND GETDATE() 
    ORDER BY 
        [date-posted] DESC
END
GO
```

Comment: You may want to edit the tags to include MSSQL, SQL and TDS tags, just as a suggestion. That said, do you _have_ to do a `GETDATE` call? It's the only thing that glaringly looks blocking at a glance. Couldn't you cache the send the date over in a string that's already formatted for Dates in the server?

Comment: If there are a lot of indexes, that could hold up inserts.

Comment: UPDATE: It turns out this wasn't the issue. The record was getting added but when the query was executed that pulls the list of records (which are displayed in a grid) I noticed the new record was missing. BTW, I've added the SP code above.

At first I thought it was something in the code causing it, some latency. But then I opened MSSQL Mgmt Console and ran a direct SELECT vs the stored procedure (which itself is just a SELECT) and to my amazement the SELECT returned the new record but it took several executions for it to appear in the stored procedure. What the heck?? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an ID10T error (mine). There's load balancer in production. Sometimes the call would get made, sometimes not because the code wasn't in sync on both systems.